# How to add a "fallback label" in sonata admin list views

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am displaying some entity relations in a Sonata Admin list view. The problem: When no relation exists (what is legal in my case) the table cell stays empty:

[image]

What I want is basically this:

[image]

I tried to overwrite the default template (`base_list_field.html.twig`):

```
$listMapper
    ->add(
        'example',
        null,
        array(
            'template' => 'AppBundle:Admin:listItemWithFallback.html.twig'
        )
    )
;
```

But even when I only extend the default template, all links for existing references stop working. Also I cannot figure out where to add my fallback. My `AppBundle:Admin:listItemWithFallback.html.twig` looks like this:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
```

With this result:

[image]

Even when I copy the whole code from `base_list_field.html.twig` into my own template, the links stop to work.

So: How can I add a fallback label without overwriting the whole default templates? I want to modify as less of the base templates as possible.

**Edit:**

This is a workaround using a `kernel.event_listener`, hope there is a nicer way to achieve this:

`services.yml`:

```
services:
    empty_cells.listener:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\EmptyAdminTableCellListener
        arguments:
            - '@translator'
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

`EmptyAdminTableCellListener.php`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class EmptyAdminTableCellListener
{
    /**
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    protected $translator;

    /**
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $path    = $request->getPathInfo();

        if (strpos($path, '/admin/') !== false) {
            $emptyText = $this->translator->trans('Not set', [], 'admin');
            $response  = $event->getResponse();
            $content   = $response->getContent();

            $content   = preg_replace(
                ';(<td[^>]*?>)[\s]+?(</td>);is',
                sprintf('$1%s$2', $emptyText),
                $content
            );

            $response->setContent($content);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to recreate the working links in your custom template:

```
<a href="{{admin.configurationPool.getAdminByAdminCode('librinfo_varieties.admin.species').generateObjectUrl('show', object.species)}}">{{ value }}</a>
```

with the fallback and all:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% if object.species %}
        <a href="{{admin.configurationPool.getAdminByAdminCode('librinfo_varieties.admin.species').generateObjectUrl('show', object.species)}}">{{ value }}</a>
    {% else %}
       {{ 'Your fallback text'|trans() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope that helps